# Parsing decimal in scientific notation

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

I'm a bit confused as to why `NumberStyles.AllowExponent` alone does not parse my decimal in scientific notation.

This throws an exception:

```
Decimal.Parse("4.06396113432292E-08",
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent)
```

This, however, does not:

```
Decimal.Parse("4.06396113432292E-08",
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent
    | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float)
```

I don't see what `NumberStyle.Float` adds (I didn't understand the MSDN documentation on it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx):

> *NumberStyle.Float*
>   Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign, **AllowDecimalPoint**, and AllowExponent styles are used. This is a composite number style.

If you don't allow a decimal point, `4.06...` won't parse.

Note that `NumberStyle.Float` also includes `AllowExponent`, so you don't need to specify that separately. This should work by itself:

```
Decimal.Parse("4.06396113432292E-08", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float)
```

Comment: awesome, i didnt look far enough into the msdn. thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

**System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent** allows the parsed string to contain an exponent that begins with the "E" or "e" character.

To allow a decimal separator or sign in the significand or mantissa, you have to use **System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float**.

Answer (score 2):

Note from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):
**AllowExponent**

> It *does not allow a decimal separator* or sign in the significand or
>   mantissa; to allow these elements in the string to be parsed, use the
>   AllowDecimalPoint and AllowLeadingSign flags, or use a composite style
>   that includes these individual flags.