# Why does AllowExponent makes Decimal.Parse fail to parse normal numbers?

Tags: vb.net, decimal

I tried these

```
    Dim a = Decimal.Parse("0.00001", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any)
    Dim c = Decimal.Parse("0.00001")
    Dim cb = Decimal.Parse("0.00001", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent)
```

The first code works.

The second line works.

The third line doesn't work.

It seems that if I do not mention the numberstyles, the numberstyles default to something. Default to what?

It basically allow parsing normal number (".00001"). However, that ability is turned off if  System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent is specified as parameter.

Why is this happening?

What is the default value of NumberStyles if we use the normal overload of Decimal.parse, without additional parameters?

Comment: vb.net and dot net framework in general

Comment: From the docs "It does not allow a decimal separator or sign in the significand or mantissa; "  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-5.0#fields

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291165/parsing-decimal-in-scientific-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't write a number with exponent other than a whole number. See my comment above.

```
    Dim cb = Decimal.Parse("1e-5", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent)
    MessageBox.Show(cb.ToString)
    Dim ab = Decimal.Parse("1e-5", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any)
    MessageBox.Show(ab.ToString)
```

Both message boxes show .00001.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that per [Parsing decimal in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291165/parsing-decimal-in-scientific-notation)

```
System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent
```

doesn't allow putting decimals.

It's probably unituitive.

Hence,

```
cb = Decimal.Parse("0.00001", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent)
```

will throw error because the parser cannot parse `.`

I have no idea why it's designed that way. So how are we going to parse 4.5e10, for example.

You need other options. `AllowExponent` seems to do exactly that. Allow Exponent and that's it.

Comment: This should be a comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Because it's short?

Comment: But that's exactly the problem. It's not very clear from the first answer. The comments are too many

Comment: I apologize. I may have misunderstood. As written, it appeared to be a clarification, not an answer.

Comment: I make the answer longer. It's basically conclusions from many other answers. They just don't tell the gist of it.

Comment: I was told that if you have something to add and it's significant, you can make another answer